# Works copied from echo but not right from batch file

Tags: bash, erlang

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob
eval="c:cd(\\\"src/\\\"),"

for f in src/*.erl
do
  filename=`basename "$f"`
  eval=${eval}" c:c(\\\"$filename\\\"),"
done

eval=${eval}" c:q()."
echo erl -eval "\""${eval}"\""
erl -eval "\""${eval}"\""
```

Here, if i copy echo output and run it from command line - its working, but last line failed( I have tested different approaches with quotes and escape chars, but unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the backslashes to be part of the string you're building (it's all quoted anyway), and you don't need the extra double quotes when calling `erl -eval`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob
eval="c:cd(\"src/\"),"

for f in src/*.erl
do
  filename=`basename "$f"`
  eval=${eval}" c:c(\"$filename\"),"
done

eval=${eval}" c:q()."
echo erl -eval "\""${eval}"\""
erl -eval "${eval}"
```